# Unificar consultas en Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

Tengo dos consultas  en la misma tabla  que cuenta con `fecha1` y `fecha2`, `fecha1` la uso cuando no se ha hecho un cierre en el mes y `fecha2` cuando el mes está cerrado  pero ahora  me piden  traer datos  de enero  a la fecha  enero y feb ya estan cerrados  pero marzo no, cuando era separado lo hacía así:

```
-----CONSULTA1 sin cerrar
SELECT 
   EXTRACT(YEAR  FROM FECHA1)                      ANIO
      ,EXTRACT(MONTH FROM FECHA1)                      MES
      ,EXTRACT(DAY   FROM FECHA1)                      DIA
  FROM TABLA1
WHERE FECHA1  BETWEEN TO_DATE('2020-01-01 00:00:00','yyyy/mm/dd HH24:MI:SS') And TO_DATE('2020-02-29 23:59:59','yyyy/mm/dd HH24:MI:SS')
   AND STATUS           = 'C'
   AND TIPO1 = 'T'

-----CONSULTA 2 mes cerrado
SELECT 
   EXTRACT(YEAR  FROM FECHA2)                      ANIO
      ,EXTRACT(MONTH FROM FECHA2)                      MES
      ,EXTRACT(DAY   FROM FECHA2)                      DIA
  FROM TABLA1
WHERE FECHA2  BETWEEN TO_DATE('2020-01-01 00:00:00','yyyy/mm/dd HH24:MI:SS') And TO_DATE('2020-02-29 23:59:59','yyyy/mm/dd HH24:MI:SS')
   AND STATUS           = 'C'
   AND TIPO1 = 'T'
```

Necesito  unir las consultas de manera que  cuando la ejecute si el mes está cerrado que  consulte la `fecha 2` y si esta abierto la `fecha 1`

Comment: 2 cosas: 1. Edita el título, escribir en mayúsculas equivale a gritar. 2 Lectura obligatoria https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Como sabes que el mes está cerrado? Hay algún valor? O es tan simple que si SYSDATE = 1 del mes significa que el mes anterior esta cerrado?

Comment: se que el mes es cerrado por el campo fecha,   para guardar datos que no son cerrados se usa otro campo, el campo fecha me dice que el mes se cerro